# How can I get values in Pop up window with xib file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

Hi I have an xib file that works as a pop-up window. I am calling PopUpViewController when certain buttons I generated programmatically are pressed.

Files:

> ViewController.swift 
>   PopUpViewController.swift
>   cityMenu.xib

In **ViewController.swift**:

```
var user: UserData = UserData()
var cityMenuPopUp: PopUpViewController!

func didTapPin(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
    cityMenuPopUp = PopUpViewController(nibName: "cityMenu", bundle: nil)
    cityMenuPopUp.userCityMenu = user
    cityMenuPopUp.showCityMenu(self.view,animated: true, cityNameText: cityName)
}
```

In **PopUpViewController.swift**:

```
var userCityMenu: UserData = UserData()

func showCityMenu(aView: UIView!, animated: Bool, cityNameText: String) {
    aView.addSubview(self.view)
    if animated {
        self.showAnimate()
    }
}
```

Currently, when I change any variable in userCityMenu in PopUpViewController, I can't get changed values in ViewController. How can I update **user** with the values in **userCityMenu** after PopUpViewController is closed?

Note: I could not find a storyboard approach using segue to PopUpViewController because the buttons that should trigger segue are generated programmatically and popupview is using xib file.